# How to select certain value from column in sqlite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a ListView in which the names of places are displayed from an SQLite database.The database has 5 columns: `_id`, `Map_no`, `Location`, `Date`, `Notes`.

When i click on an item in the `ListView` I want to be able to get the `Map_no`, `Location`, `Date` and `Notes` from the database and store them in the intent as extras so i am able to pass them to the next activity. I have tried to write my own query called `getLocation` to return the location and have looked up different tutorials on the subject and searched **SO** for answers, but to no avail.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.********************.******.***************;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;
    private String map;
    private String location;
    private String date;
    private String note;

    public MainActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        displayList();
    }

    public void displayList() {
        final Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getData();
        String from[] = new String[]{dbHelper.LOCATION};
        int to[] = new int[]{R.id.ListLayout1};
        simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, cursor, from, to, 0);


        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String location = dbHelper.getLocation(l).toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditData.class);
                intent.putExtra("Location", location);
                intent.putExtra("Date", DBHelper.DATE);
                intent.putExtra("Not_at_homes", DBHelper.NOTATHOMES);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void toInput(View view) {
        Button addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

DBhelper.java

```
package com.******************.*****.****************;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;



public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "App_database.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "App_data_table";
    public static final String MAP_NO = "Map_no";
    public static final String LOCATION = "Location";
    public static final String DATE = "Date";
    public static final String NOTES = "Notes";
    public static final String _id = "_id";
    public static final String TAG = "DBHelper";
    private static DBHelper instance = null;


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + MAP_NO + " INTEGER, " + LOCATION + " TEXT, " + DATE + " INTEGER, " + Notes + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertData(String Map_no, String Location, String Date, String Not_at_homes) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MAP_NO, Map_no);
        contentValues.put(LOCATION, Location);
        contentValues.put(DATE, Date);
        contentValues.put(NOTES, Notes);

        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + Location + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }


    }
//getting data
    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getItemID(String map, String location, String date, String notes) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + MAP_NO + " = '" + map + "'" + " AND " + LOCATION + " = '" + location + "'" +
                " AND " + DATE + " = '" + date + "'" + " AND "
                + NOTES + " = '" + Notes+ "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    public void updateData(int id,String newMapNo, String oldMapNo, String newLocation, String oldLocation, String newDate, String oldDate, String newNotes, String oldNotes){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + MAP_NO +
                " = '" + newMapNo + " WHERE " + _id + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + MAP_NO + " = '" + oldMapNo + "'"+ LOCATION +
                " = '" + newLocation + " WHERE " + _id + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + LOCATION + " = '" + oldLocation + "'"+ DATE +
                " = '" + newDate + " WHERE " + _id + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + DATE + " = '" + oldDate + "'"+ NOTES+
                " = '" + newNotes + " WHERE " + _id + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + NOTES + " = '" + oldNotes + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "updating: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "updating: Setting map number, Location, Date and Not at homes to new values: Map number: " +
                newMapNo + " Location: " + newLocation + " Date: " +
                newDate + " Notes: " + newNotes);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public void deleteData(int id, String mapNo, String location, String date, String Notes){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + _id + " = '" + id + "'" + " AND " + MAP_NO + " = '" + mapNo + "'" +
                LOCATION + " = '" + location + "'" + DATE + " = '" + date + "'" + NOTES +
                " = '" + Notes + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "deleting: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "deleting: Deleting note with values: Map number: " + mapNo + " Location: " + location + " Created on: " + date + " With notes: " + Notes + ".");
        database.execSQL(query);
    }

    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public Cursor getLocation(long id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT " + LOCATION + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + _id + " = '" + id + "'";
            Cursor rowDataLocation = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            return rowDataLocation;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Change `ListView` `OnitemClick` method code with this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            if(cursor.getCount()>0){
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditData.class);
                intent.putExtra("Location", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.LOCATION))));
                intent.putExtra("Date", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DATE))));
                intent.putExtra("Not_at_homes", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NOTES))));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi @ Aniruddh Parihar, I did as you suggested but i get an error when i write  if(cursor.getCount() > 0 ) { . It says: variable cursor may not have been initialized. Do you know what this means? Thank you.

Comment: declare your Cursor at Global level and use same cursor for getting data in onitemClick.

Comment: i have removed cursor declaration from listView onItemClick, take update

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
public String getLocation(long id) 
 {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String get_LOCATION = "";
    String last_query = "SELECT " + LOCATION + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + _id + " = '" + id + "'";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(last_query, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        get_LOCATION = c.getString(0); // Return Value 
    }
    db.close();
    return get_LOCATION;

}
```

**FYI**

> String location = dbHelper.getLocation(l).toString();

You should pass proper **`PARAMETER`** in **`getLocation()`** Section . Make sure **`long l`** holds proper **ID** .

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getLocation(l);
        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditData.class);
            intent.putExtra("Location", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.LOCATION))));
            intent.putExtra("Date", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DATE))));
            intent.putExtra("Not_at_homes", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NOTES))));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
});
```

> Inside OnItemClick, when you click on a particular item, id is taken and passed to method getLocation to give back the data as cursor. After that, you can create the intent with the result you have in the Cursor, and start your activity.

You may have to keep the object dbHelper as final for it to be accessible inside onClickItem method